# How to display custom fields in JSON response for custom post types in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to output custom fields of job_listing of WP Job Manager plugin. 
I've tried this post: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rest-api-integration-with-wp-job-manager/ And the field is always null.

I tried to return a hardcoded string, but the field is null again.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_field( 'job_listing', 'geolocation_city', array(
        'get_callback' => function( $job_listing ) {
            return "YO";
        },
        'update_callback' => null,
        'schema' => null
    ));
} );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I need to specify schema to make it work:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_field( 'job_listing', 'geolocation_city', array(
        'get_callback' => function($job_listing) {
            return 'YO';
        },
        'update_callback' => null,
        'schema' => array(
            'description' => __('Some'),
            'type'        => 'string'
        ),
    ));
});
```